# Flutter: Child bloc is initializing, but data is not stored yet in shared_preferences

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-navigation

I use for my app jwt authenctication. I have the main page with bloc pattern, which choose page to load it on screen (LoginScreen or AppScreen). LoginScreen have his own bloc pattern, also AppScreen.
When I write login and password and click login, LoginEvent is dispatched which sends request to web service and get response with jwt token, which is going to be stored in shared preferences, but in the same time AppScreen is rendered with his bloc, in this time bloc of AppScreen is sending request for data (jwt token is needed) but gets null, becouse jwt token is not stored yet. I found one work around with isn't elegant way, also I could use delay but thats not the right way...

Work around for AppScreen:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _bloc = BottomNavigationBloc(workoutTypeRepository: WorkoutTypeRepository());
    _bloc.add(AppScreenLunched());
    _bloc.add(AppScreenLunched());
  }
```

if i leave `_bloc.add(AppScreenLunched());` data can't be loaded to HomePage cuz it recives null from web service

if i leave

```
_bloc.add(AppScreenLunched()); 
_bloc.add(AppScreenLunched());
```

by first `add` data is null

by second `add` i get finally data which is provided with bloc to the HomePage

Is there any way to do it?

Start Screen:

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  AuthBloc _authBloc;
  LoginRepository _loginRepository;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loginRepository = LoginRepository();
    _authBloc = AuthBloc(loginRepository: _loginRepository);
    _authBloc.add(AppStarted());
  }


  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _authBloc.close();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<AuthBloc>(
        create: (_) => _authBloc,
        child: MaterialApp(
            title: 'TEST',
            theme: ThemeData(
              primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            ),
            home: BlocBuilder(
                bloc: _authBloc,
                builder: (BuildContext context, AuthState state) {
                  if (state is AuthUninitialized) {
                    return LoginPage(loginRepository: _loginRepository);
                  } else if (state is AuthAuthenticated) {
                    return AppScreen();
                  } else if (state is AuthUnauthenticated) {
                    return LoginPage(loginRepository: _loginRepository);
                  } else if (state is AuthLoading) {
                    return LoadingIndicator();
                  }
                  return LoginPage(loginRepository: _loginRepository);
                }
            )
        )
    );
  }
}
```

LoginScreen(part of):

```
class LoginForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginFormState createState() => _LoginFormState();
}

class _LoginFormState extends State<LoginForm> {
  final _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final _passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final registerRepository = RegisterRepository();
  LoginBloc _loginBloc;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loginBloc = BlocProvider.of<LoginBloc>(context);
  }


  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _loginBloc.close();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _onLoginButtonPressed() {
      _loginBloc.add(LoginButtonPressed(
        email: _emailController.text,
        password: _passwordController.text,
      ));
    }
```

AppScreen:

```
class AppScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppScreenState createState() => _AppScreenState();
}

class _AppScreenState extends State<AppScreen> {
  BottomNavigationBloc _bloc;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _bloc = BottomNavigationBloc(workoutTypeRepository: WorkoutTypeRepository());
    _bloc.add(AppScreenLunched());
    _bloc.add(AppScreenLunched());
  }


  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _bloc.close();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<BottomNavigationBloc>(
      create: (_) => _bloc,
      child: BlocBuilder(
        bloc: _bloc,
        builder: (BuildContext context, BottomNavigationState state) {
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('TEST'),
            ),
            body: _blocBuilder(context, state),
            bottomNavigationBar: BottomActionBar(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _blocBuilder(BuildContext context, BottomNavigationState state) {
    if (state is PageLoading) {
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    } else if (state is HomePageLoaded) {
      return HomePage(workoutTypes: state.workoutTypes);
    } else if (state is SearchPageLoaded) {
      return Center(child: Text("SearchPage"));
      // return SearchPage();
    } else if (state is WorkoutPageLoaded) {
//      return Center(child: Text("WorkoutPage"));
       return WorkoutPage();
    } else if (state is FavoritePageLoaded) {
      return Center(child: Text("FavoritePage"));
      // return SearchPage();
    } else if (state is ProfilePageLoaded) {
      return Center(child: Text("ProfilePage"));
      // return ProfilePage();
    }
    return Container();
  }
}
```

AuthBloc:

```
class AuthBloc extends Bloc<AuthEvent, AuthState> {
  final LoginRepository loginRepository;

  AuthBloc({@required this.loginRepository}) : assert(loginRepository != null);

  @override
  AuthState get initialState => AuthUninitialized();

  @override
  Stream<AuthState> mapEventToState(
    AuthEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is AppStarted) {
      final bool hasToken = await loginRepository.hasToken();

      if (hasToken) {
        yield AuthAuthenticated();
      } else {
        yield AuthUnauthenticated();
      }
    }

    if (event is LoggedIn) {
      final bool hasToken = await loginRepository.hasToken();

      if (hasToken) {
        yield AuthAuthenticated();
      } else {
        yield AuthUnauthenticated();
      }
    }

    if (event is LoggedOut) {
      yield AuthLoading();
      await loginRepository.deleteToken();
      yield AuthUnauthenticated();
    }
  }
}
```

LoginBloc:

```
class LoginBloc extends Bloc<LoginEvent, LoginState> {
  final LoginRepository loginRepository;
  final AuthBloc authBloc;

  LoginBloc({
    @required this.loginRepository,
    @required this.authBloc,
  })  : assert(loginRepository != null),
        assert(authBloc != null);

  LoginState get initialState => LoginInitial();

  @override
  Stream<LoginState> mapEventToState(LoginEvent event) async* {
    if (event is LoginButtonPressed) {
      yield LoginLoading();

      try {
        await loginRepository.authenticate(
          email: event.email,
          password: event.password,
        );

        authBloc.add(LoggedIn());
        yield LoginInitial();
      } catch (error) {
        yield LoginFailure(error: error.toString());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

BottomNavigationBarBloc:

```
class BottomNavigationBloc extends Bloc<BottomNavigationEvent, BottomNavigationState> {
  int currentIndex = 0;
  final WorkoutTypeRepository workoutTypeRepository;

  BottomNavigationBloc({this.workoutTypeRepository}) : assert(workoutTypeRepository != null);

  @override
  BottomNavigationState get initialState => PageLoading();

  @override
  Stream<BottomNavigationState> mapEventToState(BottomNavigationEvent event) async* {
    if (event is AppScreenLunched) {
      this.add(PageTapped(index: this.currentIndex));
    }

    if (event is PageTapped) {
      this.currentIndex = event.index;
      yield CurrentIndexChanged(currentIndex: this.currentIndex);
      yield PageLoading();

      if (this.currentIndex == 0) {
        final workoutTypes = await getWorkoutType();
        yield HomePageLoaded(workoutTypes: workoutTypes);
      }

      if (this.currentIndex == 1) {
        yield SearchPageLoaded();
      }

      if (this.currentIndex == 2) {
        yield WorkoutPageLoaded();
      }

      if (this.currentIndex == 3) {
        yield FavoritePageLoaded();
      }

      if (this.currentIndex == 4) {
        yield ProfilePageLoaded();
      }
    }
  }

  Future<List<WorkoutType>> getWorkoutType() async {
    List<WorkoutType> workoutType = await workoutTypeRepository.getWorkoutType();
    return workoutType;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `add` method on bloc instead of `dispatch` ?

Comment: And please show where do you initialize your LoginBloc and what's inside LoginRepository.
I think that problem may be that your LoginBloc and AuthBloc has a different instance of your LoginRepository.

Comment: dispatch is deprecated, the newst bloc have add method

Comment: newest* 

I added detail below ;) Main page where i initialize auth bloc and login page where i initialize login bloc

Answer (score 0):

Main Page:

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  AuthBloc _authBloc;
  LoginRepository _loginRepository;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loginRepository = LoginRepository();
    _authBloc = AuthBloc(loginRepository: _loginRepository);
    _authBloc.add(AppStarted());
  }


  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _authBloc.close();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<AuthBloc>(
        create: (context) => _authBloc,
        child: MaterialApp(
            title: 'TEST',
            theme: ThemeData(
              primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            ),
            home: BlocBuilder(
                bloc: _authBloc,
                builder: (BuildContext context, AuthState state) {
                  if (state is AuthUninitialized) {
                    return LoadingIndicator();
//                    return LoginPage(loginRepository: _loginRepository);
                  } else if (state is AuthAuthenticated) {
                    return AppScreen();
                  } else if (state is AuthUnauthenticated) {
                    return LoginPage(loginRepository: _loginRepository);
                  } else if (state is AuthLoading) {
                    return LoadingIndicator();
                  }
                  return LoginPage(loginRepository: _loginRepository);
                }
            )
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Login Page:

```
class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final LoginRepository loginRepository;

  LoginPage({
    Key key,
    @required this.loginRepository
  }) : assert(loginRepository != null), super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: BlocProvider(
          create: (context) {
            return LoginBloc(
              loginRepository: loginRepository,
              authBloc: BlocProvider.of<AuthBloc>(context)
            );
          },
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      image: backgroundImage
                  )
              ),
              new Center(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        LoginForm()
                      ]
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

AuthBloc:

```
class AuthBloc extends Bloc<AuthEvent, AuthState> {
  final LoginRepository loginRepository;

  AuthBloc({@required this.loginRepository}) : assert(loginRepository != null);

  @override
  AuthState get initialState => AuthUninitialized();

  @override
  Stream<AuthState> mapEventToState(
    AuthEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is AppStarted) {
      final bool hasToken = await loginRepository.hasToken();

      if (hasToken) {
        yield AuthAuthenticated();
      } else {
        yield AuthUnauthenticated();
      }
    }

    if (event is LoggedIn) {
      final bool hasToken = await loginRepository.hasToken();

      if (hasToken) {
        yield AuthAuthenticated();
      } else {
        yield AuthUnauthenticated();
      }
    }

    if (event is LoggedOut) {
      yield AuthLoading();
      await loginRepository.deleteToken();
      yield AuthUnauthenticated();
    }
  }
}
```

LoginBloc:

```
class LoginBloc extends Bloc<LoginEvent, LoginState> {
  final LoginRepository loginRepository;
  final AuthBloc authBloc;

  LoginBloc({
    @required this.loginRepository,
    @required this.authBloc,
  })  : assert(loginRepository != null),
        assert(authBloc != null);

  LoginState get initialState => LoginInitial();

  @override
  Stream<LoginState> mapEventToState(LoginEvent event) async* {
    if (event is LoginButtonPressed) {
      yield LoginLoading();

      try {
        await loginRepository.authenticate(
          email: event.email,
          password: event.password,
        );
        authBloc.add(LoggedIn());
        yield LoginInitial();
      } catch (error) {
        yield LoginFailure(error: error.toString());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Login Repository:

```
class LoginRepository {
  LoginProvider _loginProvider;

  LoginRepository({LoginProvider loginProvider}) {
    _loginProvider = loginProvider ?? LoginProvider();
  }

  Future<String> authenticate({String email, String password}) async {
    if (email == null || password == null) {
      return "Nie podanu loginu lub hasła";
    }

    var loginData =
        await _loginProvider.login(email: email, password: password);
    var token = AuthToken.fromJson(loginData);
    return token.accessToken;
  }

  Future<bool> hasToken() async {
    String token = await LocalStorage.get(Constant.ACCESS_TOKEN);
    if (token != null) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  Future<void> persistToken(String token) async {
    if (token != null) {
      await LocalStorage.save(Constant.ACCESS_TOKEN, "${Constant.TOKEN_TYPE_BEARER} $token");
    }
  }

  Future<void> deleteToken() async {
    await LocalStorage.remove(Constant.ACCESS_TOKEN);
  }
}
```

LocalStorage:

```
class LocalStorage {
  static save(String key, String value) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString(key, value);
  }

  static Future<String> get(String key) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.get(key);
  }

  static remove(String key) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.remove(key);
  }

  static removeAll() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var keys = prefs.getKeys();
    keys.map((key) {
      remove(key);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I had the same problem, did you find a way ?

Comment: I think that the repository which was using secure storage methods was initialized to late. In current project I create instance of LoginRepository in main file and pass that repo with RepositoryProvider to Bloc/Cubit. Maybe also changing from SharedPreferences to FlutterSecureStorage can be the thing.

Comment: If u have still problem post here some code I will try to help you

Comment: Thank you, i find a way by also using FlutterSecureStorage